# select columns from a table named ">"

Tags: influxdb

For some reason my code created a series named ">" into influxdb database. I need to delete this series.

```
> show series
key
---
>,Test_Prog=python,User=unknown
Bazooka,Test_Name=helloworld,Test_Prog=C,User=unknown
```

I tried

```
> drop series from ">"
>
> drop series from "\>"
ERR: error parsing query: found \>, expected identifier at line 1, char 20
> drop series from "\\>"
>
> drop series from "\">\""
>
```

but nothing works. Furthermore I cant even access this series.

```
> select * from >
ERR: error parsing query: found >, expected identifier at line 1, char 15
> select * from ">"
> select * from '>'
ERR: error parsing query: found >, expected identifier at line 1, char 14
> select * from '\>'
ERR: error parsing query: found \>, expected identifier at line 1, char 17
> select * from "\>"
ERR: error parsing query: found \\>, expected identifier at line 1, char 17
> select * from "\\>"
>
> select * from "\u003E"
ERR: error parsing query: found \u, expected identifier at line 1, char 17
> select * from "\\u003E"
>
```

Is there any other way to access/delete this series?

Answer (score 0):

Try `DROP MEASUREMENT ">"`
It's a series within the ">" measurement

Comment: Returns nothing but does not delete the measurement.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked.Could it be some process is recreating it after you drop it? You could for example run `DROP MEASUREMENT ">"`

Directly after:

`show measurements` - verify it still exists

`use _internal` - to switch database

`select * from "database" where time > now() - 1m`

which returns:
```
time|database|hostname|numMeasurements|numSeries
2019-08-20T14:04:10Z| _internal| host-influx| 12| 47
2019-08-20T14:04:20Z| your_db| host-influx| 12| 28
...
```
See if numSeries/numMeasurements for your database have changed in the last minute

Comment: I tried to replicate this issue by creating a measurement ">" in a dummy database Station_Status1 and then deleting it as mentioned by you and its working. ``` INSERT >,host=serverA value=10```. ```> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
>
Austine
Avior
Bellatrix
Bugatti```. ```> drop measurement ">"
> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
Austine
Avior
Bellatrix
Bugatti```.

Comment: But it doesnt work on my main database Station_Status. As instructed by you I tried ```select * from "database" where time > now() - 1m``` before and after ```DROP MEASUREMENT ">"``` just after ```show measurements``` but  there were no changes in the output

Comment: ok, then I'm out of ideas for now. Perhaps have a look at the log files of the influxdb service to see if there are any errors. This is a link that may help you with that https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/logs/